# Pass HTML attribute through ajax to backend ruby

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I am dynamically creating buttons in HTML using Sinatra, there is a button for every Key in a Hash at any given runtime there could be more or less buttons due to the changing size of the Hash. When I click a button I want to pass the value associated with that Key back to my Ruby backend.

My Ruby code is

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require_relative './hashmaker.rb'

enable :sessions
set :views, "views"
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do

    @hash = hashmaker.make_crazy_changing_hash(from_a_directory_of_files)
erb: index
end

get "/run_feature" do 
return runFeature(HashValue)
```

I made a table in HTML that has a button for each hash key

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> . 
</script>
            <script src="ajax.js"></script>
            <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table>
                <% @hash.keys.each do |feat| %>
                <tr>
                        <td><%= feat %></td>
                <% @hash[feat].each do |elem| %>
                  <td>
                         <button class="trial-version" name=<%= elem[1] %>><%= elem[0] %></button>
                  </td>
                <% end %>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have attempted to add the value of the hash as the name of the button, then I want to pass that name, using ajax in my jquery onclick method to the Ruby backend /run_feature get.

My current ajax looks like this currently:

```
  (document).ready(() => {
  $('.trial-version').on('click', () => {
        $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/run_feature',
                    dataType: "script",
                    data: {HashValue: this.attr("name")}
        });
  });
});
```

How do I properly get this name attribute through to my backend method?

Comment: do you mean `runFeature(params['link'])`? What is `runFeature` what is `HashValue`? Have you actually tried anything? If so what? Did you look at the url that the ajax request actually submits to?

Comment: Hi, link was supposed to be changed to HashValue and runFeature is a ruby function that I did not think was important, Im new to web development so I was not sure the best way to approach the problem, I tried using global variables similar to how I passed in the hash but they are not button specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access passed data from the ajax using `params[:link]` or `params['link']`

Answer (score 0):

You should change the datatype value from GET to POST

```
  (document).ready(() => {
  $('.trial-version').on('click', () => {
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/run_feature',
                    dataType: "script",
                    data: {HashValue: this.attr("name")}
        });
     });
});
```

and then change the function name from 
       get '/run_feature' do 
to
       post 'run_feature' do